# Код проходит не все тесты(какие тесты не знаю); C++

Tags: c++, функции, олимпиада

Задача не сложная, условие - вывести наименьшую и наибольшую цифры данного числа через пробел.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, max;

    max = 0;
    long long min = 100000000000000000;
    cin >> n;
    n = abs(n);
    while(n != 0){
        int a = n % 10;
        int b = n / 10;
        n = b;
        if (a > max){
            max = a;
        }else if(min > a) {
            min = a;
        }
    }
    cout << min << ' ' << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Но я столкнулся с проблемой - часть тестов заваливается. В чем может быть ошибка или недочет?

Comment: какие границы входящего числа?

Comment: так раз у вас есть тесты - смотрите на чем они заваливаются... они же и предназначены для того, чтобы помочь выявить проблему!

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch , видите ли, я не знаю, какие там тесты, система пишет, что пройдены не все, а какие именно - неизвестно

Comment: @IR42 число натуральное, тип int

Comment: если введенное число содержит одну цифру, то ваш блок уловий if else if не отработает должным образом, т.к. сработает только первый иф, в результате ответ неверный, сделайте два независимых блока if (a > max) ... & if (a < min) ...

Comment: @goldstar_labs Спасибо большое, все заработало, все тесты пройдены.

Answer (score 5):

Зачем просто, если можно сложно, да? :)

Просто рассматривайте его как строку...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    char m = s[0], M = s[0];
    for(char c: s)
    {
        if (c < m) m = c; else
            if (c > M) M = c;
    }
    cout << m << " " << M << endl;

}
```

Или еще короче от IR42:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    auto [min, max] = minmax_element(s.begin(), s.end()); 
    cout << *min << " " << *max << endl;
}
```

Comment: всё ещё сложно :) `auto [min, max] = minmax_element(s.begin(), s.end()); cout << *min << " " << *max << endl;`

Comment: хааах, @Harry ну вы и шутник! Строки я еще не проходил, но спасибо за вариант на будущее)

Comment: @IR42 Уговорили :)

Comment: `auto [min, max]`- что это за конструкция? Первый раз вижу. Скажите пожалуйста как гуглить?

Comment: @EOF Структурное связывание

Comment: @Harry Спасибо.